# SFDX CLI runtime error

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I'm getting the following error when trying to access the `sfdx` command. Does any one know what's happening?

The only words I actually understand are the "*not a directory*", but I'm not sure which one he's referring to either.

I tried re-installing the CLI, but it still persists.

```
17:16   Error running Salesforce DX:  ▸    stat /Users/hojasdemanzano/.local/share/sfdx/client/bin/sfdx: not a directorypanic: fork/exec /Users/hojasdemanzano/.local/share/sfdx/client/bin/sfdx: not a directorygoroutine 1 [running]:panic(0x258700, 0xc42000c180)    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1main.must(0x3bd460, 0xc42000c180)  /Users/t.dvornik/Projects/heroku-cli/io.go:115 +0x5cmain.getExitCode(0x3bd460, 0xc42000c180, 0xc42000c180)  /Users/t.dvornik/Projects/heroku-cli/main.go:42 +0x12bmain.main()   /Users/t.dvornik/Projects/heroku-cli/main.go:28 +0x14c
```

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Run a sfdx update !!

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I can't update it if I can't access the command. I did try downloading the newest .pkg and installing it tho.

Comment: Did you do an update to OSX, by chance, recently?

Comment: @pchittum I have done several updates this week, I'm not sure at which point it broke or if it was the cause though.

Comment: Sure. I was curious because this is typical of the breakage that happened when people upgraded to High Sierra (or upgrading OSX versions in general).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I eventually managed to make it run by deleting it and installing it again.

I deleted all the references to the CLI with the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/sfdx
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/sfdx
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/sfdx
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/sfdx ~/.config/sfdx ~/.cache/sfdx
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/sfdx
```

And then simply [installed it again](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli).

I don't really know why it broke from one day to another, but it's the only approach that worked. I could not update it via CLI (obviously?) and re-installing it also didn't work. I needed to explicitly delete all the references as stated in [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_uninstall.htm).

Comment: You may have gotten away with just deleting one directory instead of everything, as the auto-updater will reinstall the client if you delete it. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/223646