# SFDX 6.21.0-9db990b3c9 AND CURRENT Update - Error - sfdx no longer works

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

Anyone on a MAC got this update to work? Anyone know how to fix?

It hangs for me on finishing up.

Now all I get when executing sfdx at the cli is:

```
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/xxxx/.local/share/sfdx/client/package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxxx/.local/share/sfdx/client/dist/versions.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

Tried to reinstall, reboot, etc to no avail.

Update: After several reboots and using the download link from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm#sfdx_setup_install_cli_macos) I was able to get it repaired. All other links did not work.

Would be interested to know if others have issues with this update.

**Update 10-18-2018** Still not working. Update hangs on finishing up
**Update 12-17-2018** Still not working. Update hangs on finishing up (6.44.0)
**Update 8-01-2019** Seems to have been resolved with latest releases

Comment: I have the exact same version and don't get this error. What os / version are you using?

Comment: I was trying to upgrade to this version of sfdx from the previous version. If hung at finishing up. On latest Mac OS. Sounds like your upgrade happened without issue then?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This happens to me every couple of days on a Mac.

A workaround is to delete the directory `/Users/xxxx/.local/share/sfdx/client` and then sfdx-cli will automatically upgrade on the next command your run. See [Cannot find module package.json #666](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/666). This includes the comment:

> as discussed in #653 this was due to a cleanup process that was too
>   eager and deleted some essential files for some installs. A fix is out
>   and if you're experiencing this, delete ~/.local/share/heroku/client
>   and it should resolve itself.

**PS**

A colleague reports that "update Node.js to the latest (LTS) and update SFDX" stopped the problem from happening for him.

Comment: I assume this is correct since you use it. Do you think using it is the cause of your frequent errors?

Comment: @Eric For me it has fixed the problem multiple times including this morning.

Comment: sad that this is still happening and not fixed

Comment: Not sure how But it happen to me - got this error for any sfdx command following this post with command => rm -f ~/.local/share/heroku/client => and sfdx return to work as usual. Thanks!

Comment: Oddly I didn't actually `rm` anything, but trying `sfdx update` and listing out the directories on the system that it was complaining about seemed to have triggered something and it started working again. I was going through a Trailhead course at the time and got the failure the first time I tried to deploy a scratch org. I'm wondering if the initial failed request had to time out and clean up after itself and then the next run it was OK.

Comment: So to follow up on my above comment, I also have had to delete the recommended directory and then run `sfdx update` to get it working. A portion of my issues may be the fact that I'm behind a company proxy which might be blocking certain connections or triggering some race conditions when the components attempt to automatically upgrade. I've also been seeing  `▸    autoupdate:: /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/sfdx/update.lock is locked with an active writer` on my `sfdx update` and so sometimes I just delete and reinstall with `brew rm sfdx && brew install sfdx` to work around this.

Answer (score 4):

I got similar error on windows 10. I took a backup and deleted everything inside below folder and was able to update CLI to latest version.

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\sfdx\client

Answer (score 2):

It just occurred to me that a longer term "fix" is to disable the SFDX auto-update mechanism by exporting the appropriate environment variable that supresses updates. That way you can run `sfdx update` when you want/need an update and can waste a bit of time fixing it by deleting the client directory or a reinstall if the update process doesn't work.

> When you run a command, the Salesforce CLI checks to see if you have the latest version. If not, the CLI automatically updates itself and the salesforcedx plug-in. You can disable this automatic update with an environment variable.
>   To remain on the current version of the CLI and disable automatic updates, set the SFDX_AUTOUPDATE_DISABLE environment variable to true. For example, on Unix:
>
> `export SFDX_AUTOUPDATE_DISABLE=true`

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_update_cli.htm