# Why does SFDX update take upwards of 30 minutes?

Tags: salesforcedx

On days where I seem forced to `rm -rf ~/.local/share/sfdx/client` and then `sfdx update`, I spend roughly 20-30 minutes waiting for the update to finish. At the time of writing this, I've been waiting about 27 minutes.

[image]

Does anyone else experience this, and does anyone have insight on why this is happening?

Any info is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you "forced" to remove the updates?

Comment: @sfdcfox See this post [about no module found](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222566/sfdx-6-21-0-9db990b3c9-update-error-sfdx-no-longer-works). This is exactly what happens to me and so far has been the only solution to my "forced" problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Saleforce CLI consists of 192,290,715 bytes, 66,700 files, and 11,354 folders. The majority of the resources spent during the ~20 minute upgrade seems to be disk bandwidth according to the resource monitor in task manager. This averages out to something like 55 files per second and 10 folders per second. The most likely cause is just the sheer number of files involved; both network and cpu utilization hovers near 0% during most of the update process. I'm not sure there's much we can do about this. Hopefully salesforce.com will come up with a way to reduce this in the future. It's not a particularly computer-friendly update process.