# Specify a valid template error while creating project in VS code

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, force-cli, cli

I am currently running Salesforce CLI version 6.44.0. When I configure the project in VS code then face an error that mentioned in heading of this question.
In order to resolve the error, I updated cli version to latest one using command sfdx update.

When I configure the project then face the same error which I mentioned in below link:

[SFDX 6.21.0-9db990b3c9 AND CURRENT Update - Error - sfdx no longer works](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222566/sfdx-6-21-0-9db990b3c9-and-current-update-error-sfdx-no-longer-works)

As per solution mentioned in above link I have to delete the data present in client folder, if I do that then again it reverts to the original version which I installed earlier and if I try to configure the project then same error comes mentioned in heading.

**OS version**: Windows 10 64 bit OS

**Error**: if I am using 6.44. Version of CLI then while creating a project in VS code I get an **Error Specify Valid Template**.

Command that I am running in VS CODE is

```
sfdx:force:project:create —projectname name —outputdir path —Template standard —manifest
```

If I upgrade the version to latest one and try to create project in VS code then i get the similar error mentioned in below link description

[SFDX 6.21.0-9db990b3c9 AND CURRENT Update - Error - sfdx no longer works](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222566/sfdx-6-21-0-9db990b3c9-and-current-update-error-sfdx-no-longer-works)

Can someone please tell me how to get rid of this error

Comment: What error are you getting specifically? What command are you running? What OS are you using? The more information we have, the better we can help you. Please [edit] your question to include all the information you can.

Comment: Updated description.please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing Salesforce DX plugin, it is now working for me with the updated version and I am able to create the project.

Below is the command I run:

```
Sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx
```